# integrating the here() function with map() inside dplyr pipe operation

Tags: r

I recently read [this](https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2017/12/workflow-vs-script/) post which recomended against using setwd() in scripts and instead advocated for the here() function. The reasons made sense and I'd like to use it, but I'm having some trouble with it. Specifically, I have a function that reads in a large number of .csv files using the map function within dplyr piping. It works like the following:

```
setwd('directory with files')

files = dir(pattern = '*.csv')
df = files %>%
  map(read.csv)
```

This creates a list of all the files in the directory which I can then work with however I need to. Unfortunately, because here() doesn't actually change the directory, it just momentarily points to a directory, the read.csv function doesn't see the files. The current workaround I am using is this:

```
##no use of setwd() or 'files = '
df = paste(file.path(here('directory with files')), '/', 
           dir(here('directory with files'), pattern = '*.csv', sep = '') %>%
  map(read.csv)
```

This works, but it's incredibly clunky and I feel like there should be a more elegant solution but I can't figure out what it is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `full.names = TRUE` in `dir()` to get the full file path rather than creating the file path via pasting:

```
dir(here("directory with files"), pattern = '*.csv', full.names = TRUE) %>%
    map(read.csv)
```

Also, if I'm going to be referring to a directory multiple times throughout a script I sometimes assign a name to use for reading/writing rather than writing out the `here()` code each time.

```
basedir = here("directory with files")
dir(basedir, pattern = '*.txt', full.names = TRUE)
```